# Filter Out Rows With 3 Or More Sub-Folders

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to filter out entries of URLs that are the third level or higher. An example is https://example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3 would be filtered out but https://example.com/folder1/folder2 would not be filtered. I have attempted to create a filter using regex:

```
=filter(A2:A10000, regexmatch(A2:A10000 "https://[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/.*"))
```

There's no output that indicates I'm close as no rows get filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should simply alter your regex like this:

```
=filter(A2:A,not(regexmatch(A2:A,"https?:\/(\/.+?){4}.*")))
```

This takes into consideration possible trailing slashes to your URLs, see https://regex101.com/r/BEJYTF/1.

Comment: Close. I like the elegance of it. That includes folders with three levels or higher rather than filtering them out. What's the inverse to do this? As it's Google Sheets (specified in the tag, but I could have mentioned it), the filter is "Custom formula is". Also, a column number needs to be defined.

Comment: adding a "not" just before the regex match should inverse the behaviour, I edited my answer accordingly. Not sure to get your comment about the "custom formula is" nor the column number required, though... the formula I propose can be pasted in a new column, which will then only contain the matching values.

Comment: The filter is working when applied to a cell. The sheet is a large pivot table with 6 columns and 25000 rows so the filter needs to work at the column level with the Custom Formula Is feature. The rule logic for Custom Formula is different.

Comment: I fear I'm not picturing the expected result... any chance you could share a copy of your spreadsheet after removing any confidential data?

Comment: Here's the "Custom Formula Is" solution. Note the removal of filter:
`=not(regexmatch(A2:A,"https?:\/(\/.+?){4}.*"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, "/"))<>"", IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, "/"))&"/", ), 
 "where Col5 is not null", 0)), , 999^99))), "\s|/$", ), ":/", "://"))
```

[image: 0]